# The purpose of %@ in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I always add the following line as I write a `jsp`-page:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

But what does `<%@ %>` mean in general? I know that we can embed code to the jsp by a scriptlet

```
<% \\some java code %>
```

So `@taglib` looks like an annotation being applied to the `prefix`. Is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a [JSP directive](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_directives.htm)

> JSP directives provide directions and instructions to the container,
>   telling it how to handle certain aspects of JSP processing.
>   A JSP directive affects the overall structure of the servlet class. It usually has the following form:

```
 <%@ directive attribute="value" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<%@   >` is a tag for **[JSP - Directives](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_directives.htm)**, that can be :

- **Page directive** <%@ page ... %> : Defines page-dependent attributes, such as
  scripting language, error page, and buffering requirements.
- **Include directive** <%@ include ... %> :   Includes a file during the translation phase.
- **Taglib directive** <%@ taglib ... %> : Declares a tag library, containing custom actions,
  used in the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is a JSP Directive.The JSP directives are messages that tells the web container how to translate a JSP page into the corresponding servlet.The taglib directive is one of the JSP directive.The JSP taglib directive is used to define a tag library that defines many tags.